I just want a post-quantum permutation and I don't care about efficiency. Can multivariate reciprocals help me?
Let's say there's an application that require a public-key permutation, and we can throw all other requirements away, and design one out of reciprocal multivariate system. Is this viable? If yes, how confident are we in choosing parameters for such cryptosystem?
